# Dynamic javascript variable name using for loop

Tags: javascript, html, variables, for-loop, dynamic

I have a problem. Was working on this for a long time, but really stuck. Searching in stackoverflow for similar problems did not really help me - as people have a little different issues and I could not implement the answers to my code.

I have a dynamically changing `<input>` elements, where their ids and values are created by PHP. So, total number `<input>` elements there can be 1 or even 10+.

HTML:

```
<input id='photonumb1' type='text' value='001'/> 
<input id='photonumb2' type='text' value='002'/> 
<input id='photonumb3' type='text' value='003'/> 
...
```

There is also one `<input id="totalphotos" />` tag which has a value of how many `<input>` elements there are created.

I want JavaScript to take the number of `<input>` elements there are (probably taking a value from "`totalnumbers`") and take the values of all "`photonumb*`" (using `for()` loop I suppose?). Each value of each element is to be assigned as new variable, like:

```
var photoname1 = 001;
var photoname2 = 002;
var photoname3 = 003;
...
```

Total variable number depends on how many `<input>` elements there are created.

I was trying to do the suggestions, like:

```
totalphotos = document.getElementById('totalphotos').value;

for (i = 1; i <= totalphotos.length; i++) { 
    window[photoname + i] = document.getElementById('photonumb' + i).value;
}
```

But this did not help me, it just does not create a new variable, if I do `console.log(photoname1);` for example.

Anyone has a suggesstion for me? Thank you in advance!

----- EDIT---
Hey  @Quentin, why marked as duplicate? Maybe the idea of the question might be similar, but I am asking it completely other way, so even the answer that I am looking for is different. Moreover, I have seen that question before, I could not completely understand how it works. Thus for other beginners like me, this question might be way more useful. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. I've read that it would not be a good idea to use eval(), so I did not even try it. Maybe there is a way without using this?

Comment: Creating dynamic variable is not good idea.Why don't just push all values in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window['here']` variable was not "named".

```
totalphotos = document.getElementById('totalphotos').value;

for (i = 1; i <= totalphotos.length; i++) { 
    window['photoname' + i] = document.getElementById('photonumb' + i).value;
}
```

Beware also, that the script is executing immediately, so you have to put the script at the end of the HTML.

Comment: Hey! That worked smoothly! Thanks a lot, your answer is accepted.
By the way, I use this script in `$(document).ready(function (){`, is it also ok, or I still should put the script at the end of HTML? Sorry for asking a dumb question, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Yes, that's fine! Use `jQuery(function ($) { })` or `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { })` - they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a mistake in the For Loop.

You are comparing i to the length of totalphotos, but it already is the number of the Photos

Try

`for (i = 1; i <= totalphotos; i++) { 
    this["photoname" + i] = document.getElementById('photonumb' + i).value;
}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still no success.
I have found a solution using array, but i want the variables to be `photoname1`, `photname2`, etc., not `photoname[0]`, `photoname[1]`, etc.

Comment: Can you give me a console dump from firefox?

Comment: After `for()` loop I did this: `console.log('photoname1: ' + photoname1);` I got this:
 
`ReferenceError: photoname1 is not defined index.php:452`

Comment: Where does photoname come from?
-> AHHH I get it know...
Wait a second